# put text with variables inside UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a information which i gets from google with basic information about the user. However, the only way i can see this information is by

```
NSLog(@" user data %@",jsonData);
```

But the information will be displayed in the console.

i created a label named

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelWithInformation;

and when i'm trying to set text to this label by the following method:

```
self.labelWithInformation.text = (@" user data %@", jsonData);
```

it does not display the information on the label.

I was always confused with how to set text with variables to label.text property.

Also, i tried to do this

NSString *text = (@" user data %@", jsonData");

self.labelWithInformation.text = text;

It does not work either

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to use

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" user data %@", jsonData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.labelWithInformation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" user data %@", jsonData];
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks